# Roomba-VTZ (Vote-to-zero)

Tags: script, voting

This user script collects the voting widgets for a question and its answers, and presents them at the top of the post for convenient and quick voting.

The voting widgets will appear only on questions that are [Roomba-eligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), to whit:

- Closed
- Not duplicates
- No accepted answer
- also - deleted answers are ignored

The widgets should be very familiar, since they are clones of the ones that appear to the left of questions and answers. Your vote selections are highlighted just as they are on the margin vote widgets.

This is intended to streamline burnination efforts, and specifically the prepping of closed questions for automatic deletion. For even greater efficiency, combine it with the Tagged Question List user script (part of the [Burninator toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit)), and you can get through hundreds of candidate questions in minutes.

It should work on all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

[image: screenshot]

#### Installation & Source

This has been tested with Chrome + Tampermonkey and Firefox + Greasemonkey.

To install just [clicky here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/ed30af363a376ec4a1c2/raw/1b88f6510c8353307c171a1de7bfe3f32eaa485a/Roomba-VTZ.user.js).

The [source code is available](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/ed30af363a376ec4a1c2).

#### You got problems? Suggestions?

Leave a comment here. I'll respond as time allows.